# How to write a Custom DynamicObject class that supports object initializers

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, object-initializers

In the documentation for [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx), there is an example of a `DynamicDictionary` that allows you to work with a dictionary as if it's a class with properties.

Here is the class (modified slightly for brevity):

```
public class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is modify the class, so that I can do the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new DynamicDictionary
        {
            Id = i,
            Foo = "Foo",
            Bar = 2
        });
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how?

Comment: Object Initializers does not work with dynamic objects

Comment: @Magnus, technically, it can work with dynamic objects, but only in a non-dynamic way. So if your dynamic object had non-dynamic `Id` property, you can use object initializer for it. But this won't help to answer the question.

Comment: True, for "normal" properties ti'll work fine. I guess you colud add a constructor that takes in `IEnumerable<KeyValuePari<string, object>>` and use that to create the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I was able to solve my problem by using Linq's built-in `ToDictionary()` method.

Example:

```
public Test()
{
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new
    {
        Id = i,
        Foo = "Foo",
        Bar = 2
    });
    var result = data
        .Select(d => d.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Select(p => new { Name = p.Name, Value = p.GetValue(pd, null) })
            .ToDictionary(
                pair => pair.Name,
                pair => pair.Value == null ? string.Empty : pair.Value.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`DynamicObject` provides [`TryCreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trycreateinstance.aspx), which is meant for situations like this, but it's not usable from C#.

I see some ways around this:

1. Create a dynamic factory class. When you call its `Create()` method with named argumets, it passes it to the dictionary:

   ```
   class DynamicDictionaryFactory : DynamicObject
   {
       public override bool TryInvokeMember(
           InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
       {
           if (binder.Name == "Create")
           {
               // use binder.CallInfo.ArgumentNames and args
               // to create the dynamic dictionary
               result = …;
               return true;
           }

           return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
       }
   }

   …

   dynamic factory = new DynamicDictionaryFactory();

   dynamic dict = factory.Create(Id: 42);
   ```
2. Use non-dynamic collection initializer. This means having the property names as strings in the code:

   ```
   // has to implement IEnumerable, so that collection initializer works
   class DynamicDictionary
       : DynamicObject, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
   {
       public void Add(string name, object value)
       {
           m_dictionary.Add(name, value);
       }

       // IEnumerable implmentation and actual DynamicDictionary code here
   }

   …

   dynamic dict = new DynamicDictionary { { "Id", 42 } };
   ```
3. Probably the closest to what you asked for would be to use *nested* object initializer. That is, the class will have a `dynamic` property (say, `Values`), whose properties can be set using object initializer:

   ```
   class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
   {
       private readonly IDictionary<string, object> m_expandoObject =
           new ExpandoObject();

       public dynamic Values
       {
           get { return m_expandoObject; }
       }

       // DynamicDictionary implementation that uses m_expandoObject here
   }

   …

   dynamic dict = new DynamicDictionary { Values = { Id = 42 } };
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Using the open source ImpromptuInterface (via nuget) it has a [Builder Syntax](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBuilder). that lets you do something close to the initialization syntax. Specifically after including `ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic` you could do

```
   var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => Build<DynamicDictionary>.NewObject
    (
        Id: i,
        Foo: "Foo",
        Bar: 2
    ));
```

There are other options too listed on that syntax page if you drop the `<DynamicDictionary>` it will use an `ImpromptuDictionary` which is essentially the same thing.  And you can look at the [source](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Dynamic/ImpromptuBuilder.cs) for the build syntax too.

Answer (score 0):

When I see a pattern of embedded language like this, I tend to use extension methods, so I could write the following code to achieve my goal:

```
public Test()
{
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new
    {
        Id = i,
        Foo = "Foo",
        Bar = 2
    }.AsDynamicDictionary());
}
```

Then I would define the extension method with the code to convert any `object` (including anonymously typed ones) to `DynamicDictionary`:

```
public static class DynamicDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static DynamicDictionary AsDynamicDictionary(this object data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        return new DynamicDictionary(
               data.GetType().GetProperties()
               .Where(p => p. && p.CanRead)
               .Select(p => new {Name: p.Name, Value: p.GetValue(data, null)})
               .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value)
        );
    }
}
```

You would have to implement a constructor in  `DynamicDictionary` to receive a `IDictionary<string, object>`, but that's a piece of cake.

Comment: `p => p. && p.CanRead` You seem to be missing something here.